# Sets of divergence of Fourier series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

[Carleson theorem](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0199631) (later extended by Hunt) states that given an $L^2$ function $f:{\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb C}$, the set of points $x$ where the Fourier series $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\hat f(k)e^{2\pi ik x}$$ does not converge to $f(x)$ has measure 0.

Kahane and Katznelson [proved](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0199633) that given any measure zero set $E$ there is a continuous function $f:{\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb C}$ whose Fourier series diverges at all points of $E$.

These two results leave a little gap.

What is known about those sets $E$ for which there is an $L^2$ (or even continuous?) function $f$ whose Fourier series diverges at all points of $E$ and pointwise converges to $f$ at all points not in $E$?

There is some ambiguity with the question as currently stated, as it depends on the representative of the $L^2$-class of $f$ that one chooses. I would hope an answer would help clarify the effect of specific representatives. Let me point out that, once we pick representatives, *not* every measure zero set can be such an $E$. If $f$ is continuous, this is easy to see; in fact, $E$ must be Borel (of low complexity; and this of course seems related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/behaviour-of-power-series-on-their-circle-of-convergence/)). As pointed out below in a comment by Juris Steprans, just on cardinality grounds we know not every measure zero set can appear, even for $L^2$ functions. Hunt's extension of Carleson's result says that we may assume $f\in L^p$ for any $p\in(1,\infty)$; I do not even know whether the sets $E$ will vary with $p$.

Comment: Doesn't a cardinality argument yield a negative answer to your last question for continuous functions? (Also for L2 functions actually.)

Comment: Hi Juris. Sure; in fact, for continuous functions, the set $E$ is Borel (of rather low complexity). But I do not even have a working conjecture on what the general answer should be (does it change as $p$ changes, where we require $f\in L^p$, for example?), or whether any kind of structure can be expected at all.

Comment: I imagine this question will forever remain impossibly difficult for finite mathematicians; and even if it is someday solved, I personally am sure I will never understand the proof [or the criteria on $E$]. Having said that, it would be nice to be proved wrong!

I mean, I don't understand it, but I thought that the Carleson-Hunt theorem tells us nothing whatsoever about the detailed structure of $E$, apart from having zero measure. If even this horribly difficult theorem gives no information, I am not optimistic. The $L^p$ spaces cannot distinguish between different $E$ with $m(E) = 0$.

Comment: @Zen: Yes, as far as I can see, the proofs I know of the C-H theorem do not give us an insight, but I imagine the question here can be answered by direct constructions that do not require the use or knowledge of the theorem. 

Comment: @Andres: I've just noticed the other question "Behaviour of power series on their circle of convergence" you referred to above [together with your wonderful answer!] That question, of course, is just the special case of this question where the Fourier coefficients for negative $n$ are all zero. It seems like you've almost answered your own question!

Comment: ...but of course, the Fourier series question here is genuinely more general than for power series, I think. You can split any Fourier series into two power series in $z$ and $\bar{z}$ and apply the results for power series, but it's possible (maybe) for each to diverge, but the sum to converge.

Comment: @Andres: sorry to keep leaving all these comments, but you say: "I imagine the question here can be answered by direct constructions that do not require the use or knowledge of the theorem".

But, suppose you had the desired THEOREM: $E$ is a set of divergence for some $f$ if and only if...(DIV)

The hypothetical criteria (DIV) must somehow *imply* zero measure (maybe non-trivially). However, for (DIV) to be a useful, usable criterion, we would expect it to be possible to prove directly that (DIV) for $E$ implies $m(E) = 0$. This would then give the Carleson theorem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Zen: If we assume $f\in L^2\cap L^1$, we can choose a specific representative of $f$, by replacing $f$ with the function $\displaystyle x\mapsto \lim_{r\to 0}\frac1{2r}\int{x-r}^{x+r}f(y)dy$. I expect then we get that every $F_{\sigma\delta}$ set works, and perhaps even for $f$ continuous, with an argument that ought to be easier than what would be needed for the problem I linked to.

Comment: @Zen: What I meant is that I would expect we should be able to prove by a direct construction something like the following: Given $E$ of measure zero and $F_{\sigma\delta}$, there is a continuous (or $L^2$ or whatever) $f$ such that the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f$ precisely in $E$.

Comment: @Andres: OK, I see. That's interesting, but different to your question as I understood it; your question says "What is known about those sets...", without explicitly saying that you are *assuming* the sets to have measure zero. So it seems (to me) like you want a refinement of the Kahane/Katznelson result, and the Carleson result is a separate side-issue.

Comment: (The horrible integral 3 comments above should read $\displaystyle \int_{x-r}^{x+r}$, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem of characterizing the sets of divergence for classical Fourier series is more or less open for all interesting classes ($C$, $L^\infty$, $L^p$ with $p>1$).

The strongest result that I'm aware of is due to Buzdalin who showed that any null-set $E\in F_\sigma\cap G_\delta$ is a set of divergence for the Fourier series of some continuous complex-valued function (["Trigonometric Fourier series of continuous functions diverging on a given set"](http://iopscience.iop.org/0025-5734/24/1/A05/), *Math. USSR Sbornik*, 24 (1974)).

The characterization problem is mostly solved however for several other orthogonal systems, including the Haar and Franklin systems. There is also a very recent paper by Karagulyan where it is proved, in particular, that

> A necessary and suﬃcient condition for a set $E \subset [0, 1]$ to be a set of divergence
> for the sequence of $(C, \alpha)$-means ($\alpha>0$) of the Fourier series of some function $f \in L^\infty[0, 1]$ is that $E$ is a $G_{\delta\sigma}$-set of measure $0$.

(See G.A. Karagulyan, ["Characterization of the sets of divergence for sequences of operators with the localization property"](http://iopscience.iop.org/1064-5616/202/1/A02/), *Sbornik: Mathematics*, 202 (2011), pp. 9–33.)

---

To complicate things further, people tend to distinguish between the sets of divergence and unbounded divergence.  A set $E \subset [0, 1]$ is said to be a set of divergence (resp. unbounded divergence) for a series of functions
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x),\qquad x\in[0,1],$$
if the series diverges  for $x ∈ E$ and converges for $x \in [0, 1] \backslash E$ (resp. diverges unboundedly for $x ∈ E$).

One may think of the two optimistic working conjectures.

> 1. Every $G_{\delta\sigma}$-set $E $ of measure $0$  is a set of divergence for the Fourier series of some function $f \in C[0, 1]$.
> 2. Every $G_{\delta}$-set $E$ of measure $0$  is a set of *unbounded* divergence for the Fourier series of some function $f \in C[0, 1]$.

Conjecture 2 was explicitly formulated by P.L. Ul'yanov in the late 1960s. Both conjectures seem to be open.

Comment: Andrey, Many thanks! This is most likely the current state of affairs. I'll look at the references you indicate.

Answer (score 1):

The set where a sequence $S_n$ of continuous functions (and in particular a Fourier series) converges is always an $F_{\sigma\delta}$, i.e. a countable intersection of countable unions of closed sets.

Comment: Yes, Robert. I added a link in the body of the question to a problem where this is used. Note here that we want convergence to $f(x)$, so we are taking a subset of the set of convergence. 

Comment: Andres: I think it's the whole set of convergence: if $f$ is continuous at a point $x$ and $S_n(f)(x)$ has *some* limit, then the limit *must be* $f(x)$, because of Fejer's Theorem: the Cesaro means $\sigma_n(f)(x)$ always converge to $f(x)$ at points of continuity, and Cesaro means preserve limits.

Comment: ...Of course, for continuous $f$ at least.

Comment: In the problem as stated, the series "diverges at all points of $E$ and pointwise converges to $f$ at all points not in $E$".  So $E^c$ is the whole set of convergence.